# Help determining Maintenance Item table structure best practice

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have two different existing Database design's in the legacy apps I inherited.  On one side they created two tables; `tblAdminMaintCategory` and `tblAdminMaintItems`.  On the other side individual tables for everything; `tblAdminPersonTitle` and `tblAdminRace`.

### Method #1

Now in the first example there would be an entry in `tblAdminMaintCategory` for Race(*say ID is #2*) and then in `tblAdminMaintItems` each individual race would have an entry with the corressponding categoryID.  Then to query it for race options, for example, would go --> `SELECT * FROM tblAdminMaintItems WHERE CategoryID = 2`

### Method #2

Now in the second example there would just be an entry in `tblAdminRace` for each individual race option.  To query that would go --> `SELECT * FROM tblAdminRace`.

Now, I am trying to figure out, going forward, which of these paths I want to follow in my own apps.  I don't like that the First Method, seemingly, introduces `magic numbers`.  I don't like that the Second Method introduces many, many, small tables but I am not sure that is the `END OF THE WORLD!!`

I am curious as to others opinions on how they would proceed or how they have proceeded.  What worked for you?  What are some reasons I shouldn't use one or the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonable design to have separate entities in different tables; like: Race, Car, Person, Location, Maintenance task, Maintenance schedule. If you don't like joins in queries, simply design several views. I may have misunderstood the example, but here is one suggestion.

[image: race_model_01]

Comment: This allows you to track other information about these individual entities: RaceTrack.SeatingCapacity, Driver.CorporateSponsor, Car.Manufacturer, ect. and is pretty much a Fact of Life in relational big ciy and not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Magic numbers always seem like a bad idee. Specifically where you can use more desciptive codes in tables that do not have that many entries (Titles, Races, etc).

On the other hand having a gazillion small tables to link to not only makes the queries difficult to maintain, but harder to read and more joins to parse.

EDIT:
Smaller reference tables will make maintinance easier. Change in one place change all. But it will definately cluter up you table structure designers, and forgetting to populate these metadata tables will give you a lot of issues at new install sites.

Comment: I mean no offense, but aren't you just paraphrasing what I stated?  Which is the lesser evil?  Better options?